# Why is Dark Mode via Elementary Tweaks not working?

Tags: release-hera, settings, themes

Dark mode is toggled on with the GUI (see picture) and I've also tried system-wide commands that should of also made everything switched to dark mode, but no luck so far.

[image]

Comment: Which apps do work and which ones do not? Specifically, terminal and code.

Comment: Dark mode works on a number of apps, but here are the remaining ones that it doesn't work on:

Applications window (at top left of screen), all of the System Settings sub-menus (Power, Notifications, etc.), Calculator

I can't find the terminal command I used previously, unfortunately.

Comment: AFAIK in Hera all that tweak does is more or less just hit the dark mode switch in apps that have it, like code and terminal. I don't think Calculator or any of those other apps are affected. EOS 6 has a real dark mode integration for all apps.

Comment: Actually looking closer if you launch this command it does appear to work:

`GTK_THEME=elementary:dark io.elementary.calculator`

Comment: That command worked @KristopherIves, thank you for your help!  I look forward to EOS 6's dark mode, hopefully that'll change the rest of the apps.